# How to map a nested interface in angular

Tags: angular

I have made two interfaces

```
export interface IUser {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: IAddress
}

export interface IAddress {
    city: string;
    country: string;
}
```

Now I am trying to make a mapper service and map the data received in the interfaces and return it.

```
mapTheData(data): IUser {
    let result: IUser;

    result.name = data.name;
    result.age = data.age;
    result.address.city = data.city;
    result.address.country = data.country;

    return result;
}
```

Now from a different service file I am calling like this.

```
getData() {
    let mappedData: IUser;

    let response = //http call;

    mappedData = this.serviceName.mapTheData(response);
    return mappedData;
}
```

after http call, the response I received is

```
{
  name: 'ABC',
  age: '20,
  city: 'abcd',
  country: 'xuasd'
}
```

When I am doing the above, I get error saying name of undefined, city of undefined.

Please help me.

Comment: Probably your address is null.

Comment: Are you sending data to the mapTheData function? Please provide the data that you are passing to thata function

Comment: I have rewritten the question

Comment: can you please console log the data and update the question

Comment: done. The problem is with assignment of value, not the response.

Comment: Can you explain ? I don't understand why with this : `res.name = obj.name;` I get a error (obj.name is undefined) and with this : `res = { name : obj.name}` it's work

Comment: because, its an interface, you have to convert the interface into class, and make an instance of it like let result: IUser and then result = new IUser(); and then do the rest.. it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
mapTheData(data: any): IUser {
    const result: IUser;

    result.name = data.name;
    result.age = data.age;
    result.address = {
       city: data.city,
       country: data.country
    };
    return result;
}
```

or you can do this.

```
const mappedUser = <IUser>data;
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid hard-coded object. and that is why I have made interfaces.

Comment: For more infor read [this doc](http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/)

Comment: Thanks Anuradha, but I dont think this is going to work, as we have directly assigned values to Interface. we have to make class, make an object of the class and assign value to that object

Answer (score 0):

The address attribute is not defined. Assign the following object to your address attribute:

```
result.name = data.name;
result.age = data.age;
result.address = {
  city: data.city,
  country: data.country
};
```

Comment: I am not wanting to hard-code an object like that. Isn't there any other way ? I was already hard-coded before.. I am trying to convert it into an interface and make a mapper service to map the data

Comment: Where does your data come from, and how does it look?

Comment: I have re-written the question.

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` look like? Also you want to call `.mapTheData(response)` instead of `.mapTheData(data)` I think.

Comment: Then why don't you just do like my answer, just with `result.address = {city: data.city, country: data.country}`?

Comment: yes.. that true, I already edited the typo. response has all the attributes. I will edit more

Comment: The problem is with assignment of value, not the response received. We have to create an instance which is not possible in case of Interface. If I convert the interfaces into classes and create instance of it, It is assignable, but address is not.